# Python equivalent to R poly() function?

Tags: python, r, polynomials

I'm trying to understand how to replicate the poly() function in R using scikit-learn (or other module).

For example, let's say I have a vector in R:

```
a <- c(1:10)
```

And I want to generate 3rd degree polynomial:

```
polynomial <- poly(a, 3)
```

I get the following:

```
              1           2          3
[1,] -0.49543369  0.52223297 -0.4534252
[2,] -0.38533732  0.17407766  0.1511417
[3,] -0.27524094 -0.08703883  0.3778543
[4,] -0.16514456 -0.26111648  0.3346710
[5,] -0.05504819 -0.34815531  0.1295501
[6,]  0.05504819 -0.34815531 -0.1295501
[7,]  0.16514456 -0.26111648 -0.3346710
[8,]  0.27524094 -0.08703883 -0.3778543
[9,]  0.38533732  0.17407766 -0.1511417
[10,]  0.49543369  0.52223297  0.4534252
```

I'm relatively new to python and I'm trying understand how to utilize the `PolynomiaFeatures` function in sklearn to replicate this. I've spent time time looking at examples at the `PolynomialFeatures` documentation but I'm still a bit confused.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is a [NumPy for R (and S-Plus) users](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/r-numpy.html) cheat sheet. You can be lucky.

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at it but it doesn't seem to have what I'm searching for (or I'm completely missing it).

Comment: Could you give a description (specification) of the R `poly()` function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484053/what-does-the-r-function-poly-really-do explains what `poly` does in R

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? Without referencing the equivalent function in R?

Comment: I'm trying to apply the kfold cross validation method on a generalized linear model at different n-degree polynomials.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out that you can replicate the result of R's `poly(x,p)` function by performing a QR decomposition of a matrix whose columns are the powers of the input vector `x` from the 0th power (all ones) up to the `p`th power.  The Q matrix, minus the first constant column, gives you the result you want.

So, the following should work:

```
import numpy as np

def poly(x, p):
    x = np.array(x)
    X = np.transpose(np.vstack((x**k for k in range(p+1))))
    return np.linalg.qr(X)[0][:,1:]
```

In particular:

```
In [29]: poly([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 3)
Out[29]: 
array([[-0.49543369,  0.52223297,  0.45342519],
       [-0.38533732,  0.17407766, -0.15114173],
       [-0.27524094, -0.08703883, -0.37785433],
       [-0.16514456, -0.26111648, -0.33467098],
       [-0.05504819, -0.34815531, -0.12955006],
       [ 0.05504819, -0.34815531,  0.12955006],
       [ 0.16514456, -0.26111648,  0.33467098],
       [ 0.27524094, -0.08703883,  0.37785433],
       [ 0.38533732,  0.17407766,  0.15114173],
       [ 0.49543369,  0.52223297, -0.45342519]])

In [30]:
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: This is really useful. Do you know how to apply this transformation to new data not used in fitting, as is done in R in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/296229/223569)? How do we get the coefficients from the transformation?

Comment: I am also curious how we would be able to get the coefficients afterwards

Comment: I just wanted to add this as a comment to say Thank you and offcourse i upvoted!!

Answer (score 3):

The answer by [K. A. Buhr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7203016/k-a-buhr) is full and complete.

The R poly function also calculates interactions of different degrees of the members. That's why I was looking for the R poly equivalent.
[sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) Seems to provide such, you can do the `np.linalg.qr(X)[0][:,1:]` step after to get the orthogonal matrix.

Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pprint
import sklearn.preprocessing
PP = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

MATRIX = np.array([[ 4,  2],[ 2,  3],[ 7,  4]])
poly = sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures(2)
PP.pprint(MATRIX)
X = poly.fit_transform(MATRIX)
PP.pprint(X)
```

Results in:

```
array([[4, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [7, 4]])
array([[ 1.,  4.,  2., 16.,  8.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  9.],
       [ 1.,  7.,  4., 49., 28., 16.]])
```