# Different GLM result for Python and R with binomial regression

Tags: python, r, statistics, glm

I have the following R code with binomial regression to fit the y and polynomial of x

```r
res = glm(df.mat ~ poly(x, deg=degree), family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

and the result is

[image: R code result]

However, when I use the **statsmodels** GLM function in Python as

```python
import statsmodels.api as sm

def poly(x, d):
    x = np.array(x)
    X = np.transpose(np.vstack((x**k for k in range(d+1))))
    return np.linalg.qr(X)[0][:,1:]

res_m = sm.GLM(np.array(df_mat), poly(x, 7), family = sm.families.Binomial())
result = res_m.fit()
```

with the polynomial function created by [Python equivalent to R poly() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317127/python-equivalent-to-r-poly-function)
then the result is

[image: Python result]

Comment: Either the difference arises in the `poly` calculation or the GLM fitting (or both). Have you compared the result of R's `poly(x, deg = degree)` with Python's `poly(x, 7)` to see if the issue is there? If you need more help than that, you should probably post some sample data.

Comment: keeping zero power in polynomial would keep the constant. `return np.linalg.qr(X)[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM), the statsmodels `GLM` does not automatically include an intercept term, which the R model does. Try including a column of ones in the matrix you pass as `exog` to the `sm.GLM`. The documentation notes a convenience function exists for this very purpose: [`statsmodels.tools.add_constant`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tools.tools.add_constant.html).

Comment: Really appreciate. I add the intercept column and then the result is same as R produced.