# Polynomial Regression in Poisson Regression

Tags: python, statistics, regression, poisson, polynomial-approximations

I want to create a model which takes values from a polynomial regression and creates a Poisson Regression based upon the predicted values (by polynomial).

I only got the R code which would be something like this

```
glm(y ~ poly(x, 6), family = Poisson, data = data_set)
```

My approach so far is first calculate the Polynomial predictions for the discrete data points first and based upon this run a Poisson Regression. However, my results are a bit off.

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import glm
polynomial_model = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x=bin_mids, y=count_per_bin, deg = 6))
model_values = [polynomial_model(i) for i in bin_mids]
df_1["model_values"] = model_values
poisson_model = glm("df_1['count_per_bin'] ~ df_1['model_values']" , data = df_1 ,family = sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
```

If anyone of you see my mistake I'd love to understand where I went wrong.

Cheers

Comment: Is this question about python? Then please tag accordingly.

Comment: @Roland thx for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very sure what you are doing with binning and rest of the code. What you are doing in R is a regression with [orthogonal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials). You can see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258307/raw-or-orthogonal-polynomial-regression) for more info about why it's used.

If you are using statsmodels, you just need to provide the input matrix with transformed values of x, x^2 , x^3 then perform a QR decomposition, as also [touch upon in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317127/python-equivalent-to-r-poly-function). you can use sklearn to get the matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

np.random.seed(111)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.uniform(0,1,50),'y':np.random.poisson(5,50)})

xp = PolynomialFeatures(degree=6).fit_transform(df[['x']])
xp = np.linalg.qr(xp)[0][:,1:]

model = sm.GLM(df['y'],sm.add_constant(xp),family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
model.summary()

                     Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   50
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                       43
Model Family:                 Poisson   Df Model:                            6
Link Function:                    log   Scale:                          1.0000
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -100.45
Date:                Thu, 04 Mar 2021   Deviance:                       33.846
Time:                        22:32:57   Pearson chi2:                     31.8
No. Iterations:                     4                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          1.5458      0.066     23.495      0.000       1.417       1.675
x1            -0.2059      0.439     -0.469      0.639      -1.067       0.655
x2             0.8169      0.466      1.754      0.079      -0.096       1.730
x3             0.1178      0.442      0.267      0.790      -0.748       0.984
x4            -0.5503      0.454     -1.212      0.226      -1.440       0.340
x5             0.0035      0.457      0.008      0.994      -0.892       0.899
x6            -0.6878      0.455     -1.512      0.131      -1.579       0.204
==============================================================================
```

We write the data to csv

```
df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

and fit using R, you can see we get the same coefficients:

```
df = read.csv("data.csv",row.names=1)
summary(glm(y ~ poly(x, 6), family = poisson, data = df))

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 6), family = poisson, data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.42648  -0.73970  -0.04625   0.61351   1.81234  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.545808   0.065794  23.495   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, 6)1 -0.205940   0.439457  -0.469   0.6393    
poly(x, 6)2  0.816910   0.465770   1.754   0.0794 .  
poly(x, 6)3  0.117815   0.441847   0.267   0.7897    
poly(x, 6)4 -0.550271   0.454099  -1.212   0.2256    
poly(x, 6)5 -0.003508   0.456691  -0.008   0.9939    
poly(x, 6)6  0.687751   0.454953   1.512   0.1306    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 40.443  on 49  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 33.846  on 43  degrees of freedom
AIC: 214.91
```

Comment: For some reason I get the following Value Error when I try to use the model.predict() function. 'ValueError: shapes (1,6) and (7,) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 7 (dim 0)' Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: you need to add the intercept, ```sm.add_constant```