# exponential function does not work in r but pol does

Tags: r

I would like to fit/draw an exponential function but it does not work. For

```
before_database.frame<- read.table("APD_data.txt", 
                                  header = TRUE,
                                  sep = "",
                                  dec="."
                                 )

Single_APD.frame<- before_database.frame[before_database.frame$Serial_number==912009913, ]

# fit<- lm(Voltage ~ poly(Amplification,2), data=Single_APD.frame)
fit<- lm(Voltage ~ exp(Amplification), data=Single_APD.frame)
```

I receive:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

But " ~ poly(Amplification, 2)" works. What is wrong? I already searched for the error but the solutions do not work for me. 
Thank you!

[Data](https://www.file-upload.net/download-12593733/APD_data.txt.html)

Comment: Could you show the output of `range(Single_APD.frame$Amplification)`?

Comment: `exp` can easily blow up

Comment: @ChiPak Sure, it's" [1]    1.00252 1903.74000 "

Comment: See `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484053/what-does-the-r-function-poly-really-do`. My guess is that `poly` doesn't do what you think...You want to compare to `val <- 1:5`, `2^val` I think...

Comment: `exp(max(Single_APD.frame$Amplification))` is `Inf`, which explains your error

Comment: I didn't understand it but as mentioned there "Voltage ~ Amplification^2" looks more sensefull. How do I close the question/accept your comment?

Comment: @Ben, I wouldn't worry about closing the question or accepting an answer. Finding an answer in the comments happens all the time with posts...

Comment: @ChiPak But isn't it better when people know the question is not open anymore?

Comment: @Ben Yes...I'll collect my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is based on comments with the OP @Ben*

The error you were getting with `lm(Voltage ~ exp(Amplification), data=Single_APD.frame)`:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'
```

suggested that at least one of your values was `NA/NaN/Inf`. The range of your values

```
What is output of range(Single_APD.frame$Amplification)?
@ChiPak Sure, it's" [1] 1.00252 1903.74000
```

**-----poly-----**

`~ poly(Amplification, 2)` was not giving you an error, but `poly` doesn't do you what you expected.

```
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484053/what-does-the-r‌​-function-poly-reall‌​y-do.
```

You probably were looking for

```
val <- 1:5
2^val
```

This explains why `poly` works.

**-----Error-----**

Going back to your error:

```
exp(1903.74000)
```

**is `Inf`, which explains your error**

Answer (score -1):

Your dataset probably contains NULL values `NA`, and for this reason the function `exp` for those values, can not be calculated.
Your dataset contains NA values, or not?

Comment: Please see comments to the original post

Comment: No, it doesn't. I've included the data in the question.