# Different result from the same regression

Tags: r, glm, lm

Why do I get different results from

```
summary(lm(mpg~horsepower + I(horsepower^2),data = Auto))$coef
```

and

```
summary(lm(mpg∼poly(horsepower,2) ,data=Auto))$coef
```

PS: I'm practicing the labs of [ISLR](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`poly` uses orthogonal polynomials by default.  If you use `poly(..., 2, raw =  TRUE)` it will use raw polynomials in which case the results are the same.

If you use the default orthogonal polynomials then although it parameterizes the model differently the model still gives the same predictions. That is,  `fitted(lm(...))` will be the same for both your models.

```
library(ISLR)

fo1 <- mpg ~ horsepower + I(horsepower ^ 2)
fo2 <- mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2)
fo3 <- mpg ~ poly(horsepower, 2, raw = TRUE)

fm1 <- lm(fo1, Auto)
fm2 <- lm(fo2, Auto)
fm3 <- lm(fo3, Auto)

all.equal(coef(summary(fm1)), coef(summary(fm3)), check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE

all.equal(fitted(fm1), fitted(fm2))
## [1] TRUE

all.equal(fitted(fm1), fitted(fm3))
## [1] TRUE
```

The discussion here may be helpful: [What does the R function `poly` really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484053/what-does-the-r-function-poly-really-do/19484582#19484582)