# How is the fitted.values from lm function calculated?

Tags: r, lm, poly

I'm adjusting a response surface using the `lm` function on R. On output, using `fit[["fitted.values"]]`, the reported values are consistent with the actual values. However, when I use the coefficients generated for each effect (`Intercept, x1, x1*x2`) and do the manual calculation, the values presented are very discrepant.

How does the `fitted.values` function do its calculations?

Below, part of the code and outputs:

```
data = read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
head(data)
fit <- lm(rend ~ poly(wis, enz, degree = 2), data = data)
summary(fit)
```

The output for `head(data)`:

```
    wis enz rend
1 10.00   3   68
2 10.25   3   66
3 10.50   3   64
4 10.75   3   62
5 11.00   3   61
6 11.25   3   60
```

Part of the output of `fit[["fitted.values"]]`:

```
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11       12 
67.02258 65.46832 64.01733 62.66962 61.42517 60.28399 59.24609 58.31146 57.48009 56.75200 56.12718 55.60564 
      13       14       15       16       17       18       19       20       21       22       23       24 
55.18736 54.87235 54.66062 54.55215 54.54696 54.64504 54.84639 55.15101 55.55891 56.07007 56.68450 57.40221
```

And the summary coeficients:

```
Coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     66.23929    0.02293 2888.536   <2e-16 ***
poly(wis, enz, degree = 2)1.0  -24.26976    0.70940  -34.211   <2e-16 ***
poly(wis, enz, degree = 2)2.0  129.35949    0.70940  182.349   <2e-16 ***
poly(wis, enz, degree = 2)0.1  130.19258    0.70940  183.524   <2e-16 ***
poly(wis, enz, degree = 2)1.1 -701.60447   21.94572  -31.970   <2e-16 ***
poly(wis, enz, degree = 2)0.2    0.48360    0.70940    0.682    0.496
```

What I did was apply these coefficients as follows, considering only the significant ones:

```
rend = 66.24 - 24.26*wis + 129.36*wis^2 + 130.19*enz - 701.60*wis*enz
```

As an example, using the first values of the output of head(data):

```
rend = 66.24 - 24.26*10 + 129.36*10^2 + 130.19*3 - 701.60*10*3
```

Which results in 7897.79 which is different from estimated by `fitted.values` which was 67.02

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There shouldn't be a discrepancy - to start I'd recommend providing more details such as your `lm()` call and the expression you think should be equal to the fitted values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've supplemented my post by including my code, the outputs and the claculey by hand way to improve the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `poly()` function constructs an *orthogonal polynomial basis* by default, which is very different from the standard `b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + b12*x1*x2 ...` parameterization. If you want the standard parameterization you can use `poly(wiz, env, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)`.

If you want to see what `poly()` is doing by default you can use `model.matrix(fit)` to see what's in the `X` matrix (in the sense of a linear model defined as `y = X %*% beta`) (the actual mathematical details/definition of how the polynomials are defined is a little deep: [What does the R function `poly` really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484053/what-does-the-r-function-poly-really-do) )